# Apply jQuery off() to one table column

Tags: jquery, html-table, cell

I have jQuery `on()` applied to each table row. After user clicks to any row another page starts loading:

```
table_tag.on("click", "tbody tr", function(event) {                
    var search_id = datatable.fnGetData(this)[0];                                
    if(event.ctrlKey) {                                                                                        
        window.open("/search/"+search_id+"/");
    } else {
        window.location.assign("/search/"+search_id+"/");
    }
});
```

I added to a table a new column. Each cell of it has only one checkbox:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
```

I need to prevent loading another page after user clicking to this checkbox.
I tried this:

```
table_tag.off("click", "tbody tr td input:parent")
```

But it is not working. How can I do that?

Comment: you're binding on to the tr but turning off a click bound to td

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a handler on `"tbody tr td input:parent"`. You have just one handler, on `"tbody tr"`.

Instead, be more careful what you bind to: `"tbody tr :not(input:checkbox)"` should be better.

EDIT: As popnoodles says, the question is not clear. The above is to prevent loading a new page when a user clicks the checkbox (otherwise I imagine the checkbox to be somewhat useless). If your purpose is to disallow opening the new page if you click on rows that have the checkbox set, which is another interpretation of the question I can see, then apply the above patch to your selector, and in addition check the checkbox state from within the handler.

EDIT2: There was an error with a colon being missing; `not(...)` is incorrect, should be `:not(...)`.

EDIT-too-much: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JewCk/), with `tbody tr td:not(:has(input:checkbox))`.

Comment: He said he tried: `table_tag.off("click", "tbody tr td input:parent")`.

Comment: @JSuar: Exactly. And he didn't have `table_tag.on("click", "tbody tr td input:parent")`. You can't remove a handler that you don't have.

Comment: Each row in table has input checkbox element as first cell. I need prevent new page loading when user clicks only to this checkbox. When he clicks to other row elements page must be changed. That I mean.

Comment: @user1459172: Then yes, just change the `on()` selector as per above to restrict the handler from activating on checkboxes.

Comment: I tried it but page don't changes to another after clicking to all row space not only checkbox.

Comment: Oh, sorry - missing colon. Fixed... Try now, see if it got better?

Comment: Thank for your tryings but not working. Now he trying to load next page by clicking to a row or checkbox anycase. And also "this" don't point to row element - when I try to get clicked element by "this" keyword - I need it for fnGetData(), it is func for work with row element.

Comment: Hm, sorry, I done goofed apparently, should have tested before talking. [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JewCk/) that hopefully does what you ask. Apparently even if you click on the checkbox, it triggers on the `<td>`, so just the `:not` selector is not enough.

Comment: Thanks! Good experience for me. Selector is working correctly. How to get $(this).closest('tr') to be working correctly with fnGetData() - this I'll check later myself (it's seems not to be hard) - because have many other tasks now. Thank you.

Comment: If you need the element itself and not the jQuery object that wraps it, you can get `var row = $row[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you're trying to remove a click event from a td but you've applied it to tr.

It's ambiguous as to what you're trying to achieve. You're either trying to do something only once in which case use one()

```
table_tag.one("click", "tbody tr", function(event) {   ...
```

or you don't want the clicking of the checkbox to bubble up and trigger a click on the tr

```
table_tag.on("click", "tbody tr", function(event) { 
     if (this.target!=event) return; // will ONLY catch the tr being clicked
     ...
```

or something else